# Checking which of the statement regarding function and its inverse composition is true or not

Tags: functions

This problem appeared in Jee(joint entrance engineering exam) advanced 2005 exam : although many people said that time questions  are not fully available so it is possible that the below problem has some missing info or something : $X$ and $Y$ are two sets and $f: X \rightarrow Y$. If $f(c)=\{Y ; c \subset X, y \subset Y\}$ and $f^{-1}(d)=\{X ; d \subset Y, x \subset X\}$, then the true statement is
**(A) $f\left(f^{-1}(b)\right)=b$**
**(B) $f^{-1}(f(a))=a$**
**(C) $f\left(f^{-1}(b)\right)=b, b \subset y$**
**(D) $\quad f^{-1}(f(a))=a, a \subset x$**.

> My query is related to the subsets formation if we are sure that an element z is belonging in the inverse then it also implies that z is lying in the range that is in Y , so how can we check which option is correct here as shouldnt then all be correct ? Also is f(c) , f^-1 (d) representing a set of range and similarily domain ? Or a function as such the definition seems like of a set only here.

Comment: Your notation defining $f(c)$ and $f^{-1}(d)$ is very odd. What does $\{Y; c\subset X,Y\subset Y\}$ mean?

Comment: Exacty Sir thats what confused me too ,as i said  its from that year paper which is not fully available so mistakes can be there

Comment: Well, if you don’t know the meaning, and you can’t give a reasonable place to look, maybe you could tell us the topic of the paper so we have **some** sense of the context in which this notation is used?

Comment: Topic of the paper is to test maths at high school level in 60 -70 min . Most likely what i think  that means is that f(c) = y if c is a subset of X and y is a subset of Y

Comment: x,y,X,Y,c,d are sets probably

Comment: You said “advanced paper” in your question. In English, that implies a research publication or the like, not a high school exercise sheet. The word “paper” usually means an article rather than a collection of exercises.

Comment: Oh its engineering based exam consists of two stages jee mains and jee advanced and sry for any confusion regarding paper thing

Comment: Given the info in edit :)

Comment: The problem as stated is nonsense. It's like those clothing items you sometimes see with words in other alphabets written across them, but when you check with someone who knows the language, you discover that it doesn't say anything. Someone has mashed together standard mathematical symbols together, but with no understanding of how they are used or what they mean, thus producing gibberish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I *suspect* the authors were trying to say, though they failed **badly** in doing so:

> Given two sets $X, Y$ and a map $f : X \to Y$, we define
>
> - for all sets $c, f(c) = \{y : \text{ for some }x \in c \cap X, y = f(x)\}$
> - for all sets $d, f^{-1}(d) = \{x : x \in X\text{ and }f(x) \in d\}$
>
> if $a, b$ are sets, then which of the following are always true?
>
> - **(A)** $f(f^{-1}(b)) = b$
> - **(B)** $f^{-1}(f(a)) = a$
> - **(C)** $f(f^{-1}(b)) = b$ if $b \subset Y$
> - **(D)** $f^{-1}(f(a)) = a$ if $a \subset X$

The definitions for $f(c)$ and $f^{-1}(d)$ are standard notations (at least, if $c \subset X, d\subset Y$), so that is why I think it must be what they intended. The "set" notations in the OP are complete gibberish, however, so I could be wrong.

If my guess so far is accurate, then there is no correct answer. However, if we also assume that $f$ is *surjective* (that is, for every $y \in Y$, there is some $x \in X$ with $y = f(x)$), then **(C)** is correct.

I'll leave it to you to figure out why.

Comment: I attributed the issues to the author of the problem, but it is more likely to be a case of bad copying (from the test to whichever site you found it on, and/or by you from that site to here). It seems likely to be me that the apparent confusion between $X$ and $x$, and between $Y$ and $y$ at least is very likely to be copy errors.